# Neo4j REST return nodes, but not relationships

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am using the rest api to retrieve some data from Neo4j by passing some variables into cypher query. Following is the part of the whole code for the query and explanation of what I am trying to reach:

```
data: JSON.stringify(
{"statements":
[{"statement": "MATCH (n:`NAME`{`name`:"+name_var+"})-[:`BELONGS_TO`]->(p)-[r]->(m) RETURN p,r,m"}]});
```

The query finds the `NAME` node. The node has `name` attribute that comes with `name_var` variable. `NAME`node `BELONGS_TO`a person `p`. Now I want to retrieve all relationships and related nodes of this person `p`. In the output of query, I receive all nodes `p`and `m` but relationships `r` returned empty. I tried couple of alternatives for the query, but still cannot get the relationships. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this happens since the relationship doesn't have any properties. Maybe you want to return `type(r)` or `id(r)` instead of `r`.